# Combine two files as part of a command line parameter

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, zsh

I am trying to use csvgrep (part of csvkit) to extract rows matching one of two files. Unfortunately, there is no command line option that allows two matching files (like grep does). Only,

```
csvgrep -f list1.txt -c 2 myfile.csv
```

Is there a way to concatenate list1.txt with list2.txt as part of the command?

```
csvgrep -f (list1.txt+list2.txt) -c 2 myfile.csv
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to use a temporary intermediate file, but I would rather avoid that if possible.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with csvgrep. Can you use it as a pipe instead of specifying the filename in the arguments? i.e. `cat list1.txt list2.txt | csvgrep -c 2 myfile.csv`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Not for the pattern matching file. In this case, I'm actually piping another operation into csvgrep and then filtering on column 2 matching the a line from either list1.txt or list2.txt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want the command to see a "filename" that gives the contents of both files when read, then process substitution and `cat` are what you want:

```
csvgrep -f <(cat list1.txt list2.txt) -c 2 myfile.csv
```

Basically, process substitution is a generalized pipeline, it runs the commands inside, and arranges for their output to be available via magic file that can be opened like any regular file. The expansion itself expands to the name of that magic file. (i.e. `echo <(echo foo)` prints something like `/dev/fd/63`, and `cat <(echo foo)` prints `foo`.)

Answer (score 6):

Many programs allow `-` to be used as a filename to represent standard input or output (depending on whether it's an input or output file). So you can try piping to `csvgrep` and using `-f -`.

```
cat list1.txt list2.txt | csvgrep -f - -c 2 myfile.csv
```

If it works, it has an advantage over the process substitition method because it doesn't depend on a shell-specific extension.

If that doesn't work, you could use `/dev/stdin`. This is a standard Linux device that automatically refers to the process's standard input.

Note that all these solutions depend on `csvgrep` not needing to seek in the `-f` file, because the output of `cat` is being sent through a pipe. But this seems like a safe assumption.

Comment: `-f /dev/stdin` might also work in many systems even if `-` doesn't work for that particular tool

Comment: Good point, I added it to the answer.